# elasticsearch -no mapping found

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index: (Elasticsearch 5.5.1)

```
PUT myindex
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 3,
    "number_of_replicas" : 2
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "mymap" : {
      "properties" : {
        "data" : {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I perform the following:

```
GET myindex/_search?q=content:*&filter_path=hits.hits._source.path.real&sort=file.last_modified:desc&size=10
```

The data I receive is the data I expect all good.

if I change the call to work directly against Elasticsearch :

```
GET localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=content:*&filter_path=hits.hits._source.path.real&sort=file.last_modified:desc&size=10
```

it complains that there's **No mapping found for [file.last_modified] in order to sort on.**

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: The first request is to Kibana?

Comment: @aclokay I'm using Kibana as my test harness, but I'll want to remove that for my application and make a straight call onto Elastic. What do I need to change to get this to work with Elastic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kibana's `/config/kibana.yml` configaration file you have this entry:

```
# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
#server.host: "localhost"
```

So Kibana hits the host that is given here by default. If you use Kibana's console, the host configured here is attached automatically. By clicking the "wrench" button and `Copy as cURL`, you can check what is really send to elasticsearch.

For example hitting this in Kibana:

```
GET my_index/test/_search
```

the quivalent with cURL (without any changes in `kibana.yml`) is:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/test/_search"
```

**Update**: The point is that Kibana already knows that you are hitting to localhost because it is configured in `kibana.yml`, so you cannot put the url again because in the background it would create `GET /localhost:9200/localhost:9200/myindex/_search`. You use full url when you hit elasticsearch with some REST client (like cURL, Postman etc.). In Kibana you hit directly to index.

Comment: If I change my call to be  `GET localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=content:*` I don't get any data back. In Kibana I do

Comment: Ah.....So I need to use something like Postman to prove the call via localhost:9200

Comment: Yes, you can use any REST client you like to communicate with elasticsearch via 9200 port.